# PySpark Window.partitionBy() treats identical cell values as different

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe with columns like these:

```
df_lp.show()                               
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+------+
|                  ts|          uid|                 pid|action|
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+------+
|2017-03-28 09:34:...|1950269663250|IST334-0149064968...|    <L|
|2017-03-31 05:50:...|S578448696405|IST334-0149089179...|    <L|
|2017-03-28 09:38:...|1950269663250|IST334-0149064968...|    <L|
|2017-03-30 09:26:...| 412310802992|IST334-1212011845...|    <L|
```

`ts` is a timestamp, all the other columns are strings.  `action` can take one among a set of values (`<L`, `+L`, `<B`, `+B`, etc).

Now I defined a window, and two window functions like this:

```
ts_w_lp = Window.partitionBy(df_lp['pid']).orderBy(df_lp['ts'].asc())
first_lp = fns.min(df_lp['ts']).over(ts_w_lp)
last_lp = fns.max(df_lp['ts']).over(ts_w_lp)
```

I want to find the first and last timestamps for a given `pid`, and `action`.  So I do this:

```
df_lp_pB = df_lp.filter(df_lp['action'] == '+B')\
                .select('pid', first_lp.alias('tsf'), last_lp.alias('tsl'))\
                .distinct().sort('pid')
```

However the dataframe I get has extra rows where one of the window functions seem to have intermediate values.

```
df_lp_pB.filter('pid = "BAG26723881"').toPandas()
           pid                     tsf                     tsl
0  BAG26723881 2017-04-11 15:10:35.674 2017-04-11 15:10:35.674
1  BAG26723881 2017-04-11 15:10:35.674 2017-04-11 15:10:35.736
```

If I do the same with Spark SQL, it works as expected.

```
df_lp.createOrReplaceTempView('scans_lp')
df_sql = spark.sql("SELECT pid , min(ts) AS tsf, max(ts) AS tsl FROM scans_lp \
                    WHERE action='+B' GROUP BY pid ORDER BY pid")
df_sql.filter('pid = "BAG26723881"').toPandas()
           pid                     tsf                     tsl
0  BAG26723881 2017-04-11 15:10:35.674 2017-04-11 15:10:35.736
```

In fact, when I invert the sorting of the timestamp column to descending, the other window function has the issue!

```
ts_w_lp2 = Window.partitionBy(df_lp['pid']).orderBy(df_lp['ts'].desc())
first_lp2 = fns.min(df_lp['ts']).over(ts_w_lp2)
last_lp2 = fns.max(df_lp['ts']).over(ts_w_lp2)
df_lp_pB2 = df_lp.filter(df_lp['action'] == '+B')\
                 .select('pid', first_lp2.alias('tsf'), last_lp2.alias('tsl'))\
                 .distinct().sort('pid')
df_lp_pB2.filter('pid = "BAG26723881"').toPandas()
           pid                     tsf                     tsl
0  BAG26723881 2017-04-11 15:10:35.736 2017-04-11 15:10:35.736
1  BAG26723881 2017-04-11 15:10:35.674 2017-04-11 15:10:35.736
```

If I investigate further, I see all my `pid`s are considered distinct, even for rows they are not!  See this:

```
df_lp.filter('action = "+B"').select('pid').distinct().count()
6382
df_sql.count()
6382
df_lp.filter('action = "+B"').select('pid').count()
120303
df_lp_pB.count()
120303
```

What is going on?  Did I misunderstand what `Window.partitionBy()` is supposed to do?